# PHP + POSTGRESQL (Begin, Commit, Rollback)

Tags: php, postgresql

Em minha aplicação tenho um determinado processo para realizar teste. Este envolve banco de dados com multi tabelas. Gostaria de saber se é possível iniciar um `BEGIN;` fazer todo o desenvolvimento manual, e em caso de erro, realizar um `ROLLBACK;`.

Obs: Lembrando que estarão em momentos separados, não no mesmo processo, apenas com a mesma **conexão**.

**Exemplo:**

```
passo 1: "BEGIN;".
passo 2: processor manuais com form em html
passo 3: "ROLLBACK;" para re-teste;
```

Não achei muitas coisa sobre este tipo se situação e em sua maioria era recomendado delete em cascata ou validação em Javascript, o que não é o possível.

Answer (score 1):

Ola, você pode utilizar o PDO, veja este exemplo. Fonte [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.transactions.php)

Em alguns casos é necessário desabilitar o auto commit dos bancos de dados(mysql/postgres), pode ser feito utilizando a constante PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT

Tambem é interessante habilitar o modo debug para controle de erros com PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE e PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION.

Mais constantes do PDO aqui: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)

```
<?php
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1', 'ibmdb2', 
      array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
  echo "Connected\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
}

try {
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,0);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,1);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,1);

  $dbh->beginTransaction();
  $dbh->exec("insert into staff (id, first, last) values (23, 'Joe', 'Bloggs')");
  $dbh->exec("insert into salarychange (id, amount, changedate) 
      values (23, 50000, NOW())");
  $dbh->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $dbh->rollBack();
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

O real desafio deste modelo, seria ter tabelas de bases de dados distintas em uma mesma transação...acho q seria uma outra questão.

Comment: Muito instrutivo Willian, contudo a estrutura do Frameword, não permite a conexão persistente.
E em seu exemplo, você utilizou o padrão da Transaction, na qual o BEGIN esta no mesmo processo do COMMIT e ROLLBACK, que não aborda minha necessidade de processos separados.
Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: de nada, tamos ae